# Pairwise distance matrix between two vectors

Tags: julia

```
x1=[1,2,3]
x2=[2,3,4]
```

how to find the Pairwise distance matrix between `x1` and `x2` (distance matrix should be a 3 x 3 matrix)

Comment: It SHOULD be a 2x2 matrix: `[[0.0 , norm(x1-x2)^2][norm(x1-x2)^2, 0]]`

Comment: Since I want to calculate the pairwise distance matrix. So for example the distance between (1,2) and (2,3). There are total 9 pairs. So it should be a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance_matrix is what you mean? They do not fiddle with components. 2 Vectors => 2x2 matrix. N vectors NxN matrix.

Comment: I need to find the distance of 9 pairs of matrix:(1,2)and(2,3), (1,2)and(2,4), (1,2)and(3,4), (1,3)and(2,3), (1,3)and(2,4), (1,3)and(3,4), (2,3)and(2,3), (2,3)and(2,4), (2,3)and(3,4). So the overall distance matrix is a 3x3.

Comment: I've removed the tag information from the title again. Please do not add noise  to the title by unnecessarily repeating information already available in the tags.

Comment: How do you define pair-wise distance between two vectors in math? Their seems to be a disconnect between what you want and what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Euclidean distance matrix, but it is 3 X 3. Is it what you want?

```
julia> x1 = [1,2,3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> x2 = [2,3,4]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 3
 4

julia> [(a-b)^2 for a in x1, b in x2]
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  4  9
 0  1  4
 1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
abs.(x1 .- x2')
#3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
# 1  2  3
# 0  1  2
# 1  0  1
```

Where `x2'` turns `x2` in a column vector and `.-` and `abs.` makes element wise operations.
Or creating the desired pairs (1,2)and(2,3), (1,2)and(2,4), ...  (2,3)and(3,4) and calculating the distance using `norm`.

```
using LinearAlgebra

#Create pairs
c1 = [(x1[i], x1[j]) for i in 1:lastindex(x1)-1 for j in i+1:lastindex(x1)]
c2 = [(x2[i], x2[j]) for i in 1:lastindex(x2)-1 for j in i+1:lastindex(x2)]

#Calc distance
[norm(i.-j) for i in c1, j in c2]
#3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
# 1.41421  2.23607  2.82843
# 1.0      1.41421  2.23607
# 0.0      1.0      1.41421

#Calc cityblock distance
[norm(i.-j, 1) for i in c1, j in c2]
#3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
# 2.0  3.0  4.0
# 1.0  2.0  3.0
# 0.0  1.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for Euclidean distance between all combinations of vector pairs from `x1` and `x2`, that's, the distance between [1, 2] and [2, 3], [1, 2] and [2, 4], ..., [2, 3] and [3, 4], this can be done as follows:

Using [Combinatorics.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Combinatorics.jl), construct all pairs from `x1` by taking 2 elements at a time. Do the same for `x2`. Now you have `c1` and `c2`, just loop over the two sequences applying the formal definition of Euclidean distance, `sqrt(sum((x-y)^2))`, to get the 3-by-3 matrix of pairwise distances that you want.

```
using Combinatorics

x1 = [1, 2, 3]
x2 = [2, 3, 4]

c1 = combinations(x1, 2)
c2 = combinations(x2, 2)

pairwise = [sqrt(sum((i.-j).^2)) for i in c1, j in c2]
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.41421  2.23607  2.82843
 1.0      1.41421  2.23607
 0.0      1.0      1.41421
```

If you like higher-order index notations similar to math books, you can use [Tullio.jl](https://github.com/mcabbott/Tullio.jl) like this:

```
using Tullio

x = collect(combinations(x1, 2))
y = collect(combinations(x2, 2))

@tullio pairwise[i,j] := sqrt(sum((x[i].-y[j]).^2))
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.41421  2.23607  2.82843
 1.0      1.41421  2.23607
 0.0      1.0      1.41421
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Distances.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl):

```
julia> pairwise(Euclidean(), x1, x2)
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0
 0.0  1.0  2.0
 1.0  0.0  1.0
```

(Although this will not return integers, as it uses BLAS stuff internally.)